# jQuery Color Animation - does not fade back to background color

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use a jQuery color animation plugin http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/. When we call it and pass it, say `#FFFF00` (yellow), we see it change to yellow and fade away. But it never quite fades back to the element's original background color, which is white `#FFFFFF`. After doing a DOM inspection, I noticed that the elements ended up with a variety of styles added to it, such as:

- `style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 215);`
- `style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 149);`
- `style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 207);`

What do we need to do to get the plugin to work in such a way that at the end, the background color is the original color.

Comment: probably would help if you posted the code you're using to trigger the animation(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the plugin. The author has fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2):

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/ajibej/1/edit)*

you could use **jQuery UI** and this:

```
$('.box').hover(function(){
   $(this).stop().animate({backgroundColor: '#ff0'});
},function(){
   $(this).stop().animate({backgroundColor: '#fff'});
});
```

Or your problem might just be you're not clearing your 
animations queue using `.stop()`

Comment: We're using jQuery Tools. That's why we opted for that plugin.